# Ajax called more than once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one problem with my ajax code. It is called more than once. My php code is next :

(*While loop where I get all results from a database. I pasted only a modal and a dropdown menu because everything else works fine*)

```
$rezPet = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM pets WHERE user_id = ". $userId ." ORDER BY id DESC");
while($redPet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezPet)){


......
<div id=\"confirmBox-". $redPet["id"] ."\" class=\"modal fade bs-example-modal-xs\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"mySmallModalLabel\">
    <div class=\"modal-dialog modal-sm\">
      <div class=\"modal-content\">
            <div class=\"modal-header\">
                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-label=\"Close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class=\"modal-title\" id=\"myModalLabel\"><b>". $redPet["name"] ."</b> is gevonden?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class=\"modal-body\">
                Bent u zeker dat <b>". $redPet["name"] ."</b> gevonden is?
            </div>
            <div class=\"modal-footer\">
                <button id=\"btnFoundCancel-". $redPet["id"] ."\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-dismiss=\"modal\"><i class=\"fa fa-ban\"></i>  Cancel</button>
                <button id=\"btnFoundConfirm-". $redPet["id"] ."\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-dismiss=\"modal\"><i class=\"fa fa-floppy-o\"></i>  Ja! Ga verder</button>
            </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

.
.
.
<div id=\"dropdown-". $redPet["id"] ."\" class=\"col-md-6 col-xs-12\" style=\"padding-right:10px;z-index:99999999;". $showHideDropdown ."\">
        <!-- Split button -->
        <div class=\"btn-group pull-right\">
        <button type=\"button\" id=\"dataTitle\" data-title=\"Beheer informatie over uw dier\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-xs\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil-square-o\"></i></button>
        <button type=\"button\" id=\"dataTitle\" data-title=\"Beheer informatie over uw dier\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-haspopup=\"true\" aria-expanded=\"false\">
        <span class=\"caret\" style=\"margin-top:0;\"></span>
        <span class=\"sr-only\">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul id=\"drpDown-". $redPet["id"] ."\" class=\"dropdown-menu\">
                <li class=\"col-lg-12\">
                    <button id=\"dataTitle btnFound-". $redPet["id"] ."\" class=\"btnFound btn btn-success col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn-sm\" data-title=\"Klik hier als uw dier gevonden is\" data-target=\"#confirmBox-". $redPet["id"] ."\" data-toggle=\"modal\"><i class=\"fa fa-home\"></i>  Gevonden</button>
                </li>
                <div style=\"clear:both;\"></div><li role=\"separator\" class=\"divide5\"></li>
                <li class=\"col-lg-12\">
                    <form action=\"dier-toevoegen.php\" method=\"POST\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"changeID\" value=\"". $redPet["id"] ."\">
                        <button id=\"dataTitle\" class=\"btn btn-info col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn-sm\" data-title=\"Klik hier om de informatie over uw dier te wijzigen\" type=\"submit\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i>  Wijzigen</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
                <div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>
                <li role=\"separator\" class=\"divider\"></li>
                <li class=\"col-lg-12\">
                    <button id=\"dataTitle btnVerwijderen-". $redPet["id"] ."\" class=\"linkDelete btn btn-danger col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn-sm\" data-title=\"Klik hier om uw dier te verwijderen\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i>  Verwijderen</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

My ajax code is next :

(*First ajax code, where I update database field found to value 1, it works fine, the only problem is because it has been call more the once*)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click","button[class*=btnFound]", function(e){
            var cijeliID = this.id.split("-");
            var id = cijeliID[1];
            $($("#confirmBox-"+id).data("target")).fadeIn(400);

            $(document).on("click", "#btnFoundConfirm-"+id, function(){
                /*$("#confirmBox-"+id).modal('toggle');*/
                $.ajax({
                    url : "pet-found.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data : {id : id, status:"found", sessionCode : "<?php echo $session_code; ?>"},
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#info-middle-register").show();
                    },

                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#info-middle-register").hide();
                        if(msg.result == "Found"){
                            $("#delpetsuccess-"+id).html("<i class=\"fa fa-thumbs-o-up\"></i>  Uw huisdier is thuis. De VermisteDieren site wenst u veel plezier met uw beestje.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
                            $("#watermark-"+id).show();
                            $("#drpDown-"+id).html("<li id=\"liTochGezocht-"+id+"\" class=\"col-lg-12\"><button id=\"dataTitle btnNotFound-"+id+"\" class=\"btnNotFound btn btn-primary col-lg-12 xol-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn-sm\" data-title=\"Klik hier als uw beestje toch nog niet gevonden is.\"><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left\"></i>  Toch nog gezocht?</button></li>");
                            $("#dier-"+id).addClass("opacityClass");

                        }else{
                            if(msg.result == "NotFound"){
                                $("#delpeterror-"+id).html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>  Er is iets misgelopen. Contacteer ons via info@vermistedieren.be.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    error: function(){
                        $("#info-middle-register").hide();
                        $("#delpeterror-"+id).html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>  Er is iets misgelopen. Contacteer ons via info@vermistedieren.be.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
                    }
                })
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

(Second code, where I update database field found to value 0)

```
<!-- Ako klikne na go back kada je zivotinja oznacena kao pronadjena -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click","button[class*=btnNotFound]", function(e){
            var cijeliID = this.id.split("-");
            var id = cijeliID[1];

            $.ajax({
                url : "pet-found.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data : {id : id, status:"notFound", sessionCode : "<?php echo $session_code; ?>"},
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#info-middle-register").show();
                },

                success: function(msg){
                    $("#info-middle-register").hide();
                    if(msg.result == "changeMindNotFound"){
                        $("#watermark-"+id).hide();
                        $("#dier-"+id).removeClass("opacityClass");
                        $("#txtFound-"+id).hide();
                        $("#liTochGezocht-"+id).hide();
                        $("#drpDown-"+id).html("<li class=\"col-lg-12\"><button id=\"dataTitle btnFound-"+id+"\" class=\"btnFound btn btn-success col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn-sm\" data-title=\"Klik hier als uw dier gevonden is\" data-target=\"#confirmBox-"+id+"\" data-toggle=\"modal\"><i class=\"fa fa-home\"></i>  Gevonden</button></li><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div><li role=\"separator\" class=\"divide5\"></li><li class=\"col-lg-12\"><form action=\"dier-toevoegen.php\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"changeID\" value=\""+id+"\"><button id=\"dataTitle\" class=\"btn btn-info col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn-sm\" data-title=\"Klik hier om de informatie over uw dier te wijzigen\" type=\"submit\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i>  Wijzigen</button></form></li><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div><li role=\"separator\" class=\"divider\"></li>                                            <li class=\"col-lg-12\"><button id=\"dataTitle btnVerwijderen-"+id+"\" class=\"linkDelete btn btn-danger col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn-sm\" data-title=\"Klik hier om uw dier te verwijderen\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i>  Verwijderen</button></li>");

                    }else{
                        if(msg.result == "changeMindFound"){
                            $("#delpeterror-"+id).html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>  Er is iets misgelopen. Contacteer ons via info@vermistedieren.be.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
                        }
                    }
                },

                error: function(){
                    $("#info-middle-register").hide();
                    $("#delpeterror-"+id).html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>  Er is iets misgelopen. Contacteer ons via info@vermistedieren.be.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

When the page loads first time, if I click on "Gevonden" button, than is everything perfect. The first ajax code is called once and it is ok.
But than are the list items of a dropmenu changed to only one button ("toch nog gezoch"). If I click on it, than is second ajax code called and it does what it need to do.

Then are the list items in a dropdown menu changed again to the first three buttons (Gevonden, Wijzigen, Verwijderen). And than I get a problem. When I then click on gevonden button, the first ajax code is called two times. And every next try is the first ajax code called one time more.

Any syggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're binding to a `click` event within another `click` event handler.  That makes alarm bells ring.

Comment: @JamesThorpe When I first time click on Gevonden button, it is also a click inside a click, but then it works good.

Comment: The second time you invoke the first click handler though, you're adding _another_ click handler to `"#btnFoundConfirm-"+id`.  Next time you click that, it will run the inner handler twice.

Comment: @JamesThorpe suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: If you can't restructure the code to avoid the nested handlers, the simplest solution is to unbind any pre-existing click handlers before rebinding.

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: Feel free to post and accept your own answer, rather than posting the solution in the question itself - it's [perfectly acceptable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. I separated one click event of another as @JamesThorpe said.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click","button[class*=btnFound]", function(e){
            var cijeliID = this.id.split("-");
            var id = cijeliID[1];
            $($("#confirmBox-"+id).data("target")).fadeIn(400);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".btnFoundConfirm", function(){
        var cijeliID = this.id.split("-");
        var id = cijeliID[1];
        /*$("#confirmBox-"+id).modal('toggle');*/
        $.ajax({
            url : "pet-found.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {id : id, status:"found", sessionCode : "<?php echo $session_code; ?>"},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#info-middle-register").show();
            },

            success: function(msg){
                $("#info-middle-register").hide();
                if(msg.result == "Found"){
                    $("#delpetsuccess-"+id).html("<i class=\"fa fa-thumbs-o-up\"></i>  Uw huisdier is thuis. De VermisteDieren site wenst u veel plezier met uw beestje.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
                    $("#watermark-"+id).show();
                    $("#drpDown-"+id).html("<li id=\"liTochGezocht-"+id+"\" class=\"col-lg-12\"><button id=\"dataTitle btnNotFound-"+id+"\" class=\"btnNotFound btn btn-primary col-lg-12 xol-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn-sm\" data-title=\"Klik hier als uw beestje toch nog niet gevonden is.\"><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left\"></i>  Toch nog gezocht?</button></li>");
                    $("#dier-"+id).addClass("opacityClass");

                }else{
                    if(msg.result == "NotFound"){
                        $("#delpeterror-"+id).html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>  Er is iets misgelopen. Contacteer ons via info@vermistedieren.be.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
                    }
                }
            },

            error: function(){
                $("#info-middle-register").hide();
                $("#delpeterror-"+id).html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>  Er is iets misgelopen. Contacteer ons via info@vermistedieren.be.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
            }
        })
    });
});

</script>
```

And in a modal button (Ja! Ga verder) I added a class btnFoundConfirm and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click","button[class*=btnNotFound]", function(e){

          // add this around
          if (e.handled !== true) {
            e.handled = true; // prevent firing two times

            // your code


          }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a project I am working and this is how I solved it (this is actual code sample from the project):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    var didItRun = false; //I'm using this boolean to check if I already ran this code.
    $('#filterForm2GoodsReceived input').change(function () {
        if(didItRun == false)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Receiving/List/",
                data: $('#filterForm2GoodsReceived').serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#listReceivingOrders').html(response);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            didItRun = true;
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the reply, but the problem still exists. This solution is similar to the Eric Pörschmann's solution. But it won't work.